# Run a form in a separate thread

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-2010

Let's say I have a form Foo.
How do I create an instance of that which runs in it's own thread and gets updated even though the main application thread might be busy doing something else? For instance handling blocking network communication or something like that.

I understand the fundamentals and that I need to create a new thread, create the form instance in that thread etc. But then I figure I need an update loop for that thread/window and I'm not at all sure how that should look.

Comment: VCL runs all forms on the main thread, if the main thread blocks then the entire application blocks.

Comment: @GregorBrandt: Thank you. So even forms created in a secondary thread is still connected to and run from the main thread? You have any references for this? Why does VCL always have to be different ;).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create forms in threads any than your main application thread, because windows message queue is associated only with this main thread.
Think differently: To be sure, that your forms are always updated and responsive, create separate threads for busy work like handling blocking newtork communications and so on, not for forms. In such case, after creating new thread, main form continues to pump messages from it's queue, while function in different thread is doing dirty-work that you need. When the working thread finishes, it can inform main thread about results, using `PostMessage()` WinAPI function. You should just simply provide handlers for such custom messages in your forms, and they will communicate with working threads seamlessly.
Also, if your "busy work" isn't very complicated, you can even deal without additional threads, by running your work in the form thread, and just calling `ProcessMessages()` function from time to time, to keep the form updated.

Comment: This is for a large application already in place. Having a form displaying and being updated without caring if the main thread is bogged down is the quick way to fix this. Otherwise one has to re-write a lot of code. I have been told this is doable and that the new form can has it's own message processing thread.
The usage for this is to have a notification being displayed (and animated) while the main thread is doing work.

Comment: May be it will be useful to go from multi-thread to multi-process and create separate mini-application displaying the form you need. Standard windows messaging can be used to communicate between forms and no additional work related to making separate queues will be necessary in this case.

Comment: Well, since I want that "popup" to be able to "lock" the main window that would be a bit fiddly. Strange since it's so easy in C# for example and even C++ MFC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990857/running-a-windows-form-in-a-separate-thread